# TuneLength definition in Caret R

Tags: r, r-caret

How does `tuneLength` work in different models in the train function of the Caret package?

```
ctreeModel <- train(CompressiveStrength ~ .,
+ data = trainingSet,
+ method = "ctree",
+ tuneLength = 10,
+ trControl = controlObject)
```

In this case, has `tuneLength` been used to define the number of predictors that are used in each split?

Comment: Please read the documentation at https://topepo.github.io/caret

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the model. A valuable function within caret is `modelLookup()`. Pass a string with the name of the model you’re using, for example `modelLookup("rf")` and it will tell you which parameter is being tuned by `tunelength`. In your case above :

```
> modelLookup("ctree")
  model    parameter                 label forReg forClass probModel
1 ctree mincriterion 1 - P-Value Threshold   TRUE     TRUE      TRUE
```

You can also specify your own range of tuning in a more customized way, if you want to try out specific values. For that, pass a data frame with column names matching those of the arguments from `modelLookup()` or if you have many of them for the specific model you're using, try `expand.grid()`.